# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 - GraphRawResponse.php

Tags: php

I am getting this PHP error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Code is:

```
public function setHttpResponseCodeFromHeader($rawResponseHeader)
{
    preg_match('|HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)\s+.*|', $rawResponseHeader, $match);
    $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1];
}
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the array $match initialized before you accessing it?
Try that before you accessing $match

```
$match = [];
//or
$match = array();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem is fixed using $match = array(); You wrote me $math, edit that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, problem :D I've edited the variable